# Unable to find a way to convert a UTC timestamp to ISO format in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, utc, iso

I am looking to convert "Thu Jul 09 17:05:42 +0000 2020" this string into ISO format in Python.
I searched on internet but didn't find any useful information.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using? If you are reading the date in as a `date object`, python supports format strings for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `datetime` object from the given string and then use the `datetime.isoformat()` to convert it to ISO format.

```py
from datetime import datetime

mydate = datetime.strptime("Thu Jul 09 17:05:42 +0000 2020", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
print(mydate.isoformat())
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-09T17:05:42+00:00
```

You can read more about formatting the date from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)